# Z-index prevents item to get clicked

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, dropshadow

I have a container div with inset drop shadow on it, I also have child elements inside of this container, and I simply want these children to be clickable.

Setting the children (images in my project, not sure if it matters) element's z-index to -1 is essential for the drop shadow to show. But doing that the container will cover the child elements, so click won't work.

Setting pointer-events: none; on the container element didn't help either (I also want the container to be scrollable).

```js
$('.item').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .item {
      width: 250px;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 3px 0;
      background-color: #cacaca;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: -1;
      /*Shadow visible, JS doesn't work*/
      /*z-index: 0;*/
      /*Clickable, but shadow is covered */
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" id="item1">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item2">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item3">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="item1">
    <p>CLICK</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oe841sw/4/)

How can I keep the shadow, and make the child elements clickable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why its happening

The reason this is happening is because the divs with the class `.item` is behind the `.container`, meaning the user is in fact clicking on the `.container`, NOT the `.item`.

### Solution

You can wrap your div's with a wrapper like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" id="item1">
        <div><p>CLICK</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="item2">
        <div><p>CLICK</p></div>
    </div>    

    <div class="item" id="item2">
        <div><p>CLICK</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="item3">
        <div><p>CLICK</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and update your CSS from `.item` to `.item > div` [BUT leave the JS as it is]

This way, the outer `.item` is still in front of the `.container` and the inner div is behind the `.container`, meaning it's still clickable and you get the styling you want!

### Proof it works!

Check the following JS Fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/anik786/5oe841sw/6/

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Proof that it works!]

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the issue. Click on the .item elements still doesn't work.

Comment: Check my JS Fiddle. You may have looked at an old link. I edited the question and it works fine!

Comment: Yes, I looked at an old link. It works fine, thank you.